# NGinx: connect() to unix:/var/run/hhvm/sock failed, No such file

Tags: nginx, hhvm

I am Tryig to install FB-CTF  which uses HHVM, and NGinx. Everything is set completely by Shell command itself.. but now error log showing

```
2017/01/18 21:48:17 [crit] 15143#0: 
***6 connect() to unix:/var/run/hhvm/sock failed** 
(2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,
client: 127.0.0.1, server: ,
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/hhvm/sock:",
host: "localhost"
```

actually `/var/run/hhvm/` contains only `hhvm.hhbc`.. getting **502 BAD GATEWAY**

Comment: You try to connect to the upstream unix socket which does not exist. Do you have fastcgi setup if yes where did you point the socket to to be created?

Comment: yes i have... actually, i am a beginer in server setup using hhvm or nginx and all..  can u little bit describe it @DanFromGermany

Comment: Got that problem solved when reinstalled hhvm..

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled HHVM. then missing files are reinstalled. all the dependent files are correctly restored.